# show the li that has an anchor link which has a data attribute name "data-link" that match unto specified text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Base from my snippets below, firstly, If i clicked unto any branch from a dropdown that has a label of "select branch", then it will get the text from a clicked branch (anchor link e.g. Iligan) and then hide all the li's from the ul of a dropdown that has a label of "select user" and then show all li's that has a link with a data attribute named "data-link" and its content match on the text of the select branch dropdown currently clicked link but sadly not working, I can hide all li's but unable to show those li that has an anchor link with a data attribute named "data-link" which data-link content is matched to the text of the currently clicked link from the select branch dropdown. Any help, suggestions, clues, recommendations, ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
//user change pass on user management
    $(".uu .uu_dp a").click(function(e){
        $(this).parents(".uu").find(".unregistered_user").text("User: " + $(this).text());
        $(this).parents(".uu").find(".unregistered_user").attr("data-link", $(this).attr("data-link"));
        bbr = $(this).parents(".uc_header").next().find(".uu_cp_form fieldset");
        $(this).parents(".daselect").next().find("form").slideDown();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //u branch on user management
    $(".ub .ub_dp a").click(function(e){
        $(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").text("Branch: " + $(this).text());
        $(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").attr("data-link", $(this).attr("data-link"));
        $(this).parents(".daselect").find(".uu .uu_dp li").hide();
        (this).parents(".daselect").find('.uu .uu_dp li a[data-link="Iligan"]').show;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="extend clear daselect">
                <div class="btn-group ub align_left margin_right5px">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default u_branch" data-toggle="dropdown">Select branch</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>

                    <ul class="ub_dp dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp">Iligan</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp">Corporate</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp">Initao</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group uu align_left">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default unregistered_user" data-toggle="dropdown">Select User</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>

                  <ul class="uu_dp dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="height: 300px;">
                        <li><a href="#" data-id="1" data-link="Iligan">User 1 of Iligan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-id="2" data-link="Iligan">User 2 of Iligan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-id="3" data-link="Iligan">User 3 of Iligan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-id="4" data-link="Corporate">User 1 of Corporate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-id="5" data-link="Corporate">User 2 of Corporate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-id="6" data-link="Initao">User 1 of Initao</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this putting the data attribute named "data-link" to the li parent of each anchor link that inside the ul that has a class of "uu_dp" and then update your code like below.

```
$(".ub .ub_dp a").click(function(e){
    $(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").text("Branch: " + $(this).text());
    $(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").attr("data-link", $(this).attr("data-link"));
    $(this).parents(".daselect").find(".uu .uu_dp li").hide();
    $(this).parents(".daselect").find('.uu .uu_dp li[data-link="' + $(this).text() + '"]').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found some issues, Kindly go through the comments:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="45;URL=http://otherpage.com.br">
</head>
<body>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="extend clear daselect">
        <div class="btn-group ub align_left margin_right5px">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default u_branch" data-toggle="dropdown">Select branch</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>

            <ul class="ub_dp dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp">Iligan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp">Corporate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp">Initao</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group uu align_left">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default unregistered_user" data-toggle="dropdown">Select User</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>

            <ul class="uu_dp dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="height: 300px;">
                <li><a href="#" data-id="1" data-link="Iligan">User 1 of Iligan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-id="2" data-link="Iligan">User 2 of Iligan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-id="3" data-link="Iligan">User 3 of Iligan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-id="4" data-link="Corporate">User 1 of Corporate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-id="5" data-link="Corporate">User 2 of Corporate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-id="6" data-link="Initao">User 1 of Initao</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".uu .uu_dp a").click(function(e){
            $(this).parents(".uu").find(".unregistered_user").text("User: " + $(this).text());
            $(this).parents(".uu").find(".unregistered_user").attr("data-link", $(this).attr("data-link"));
            bbr = $(this).parents(".uc_header").next().find(".uu_cp_form fieldset");
            $(this).parents(".daselect").next().find("form").slideDown();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        //u branch on user management
        $(".ub .ub_dp a").click(function(e){
            $(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").text("Branch: " + $(this).text());
            $(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").attr("data-link", $(this).attr("data-link"));
            //$(this).attr("data-link") will return undefined as clicked element does not have "data-link" attribute
            $(this).parents(".daselect").find(".uu .uu_dp li").hide();
            $(this).parents(".daselect").find('.uu .uu_dp li a[data-link="Iligan"]').show();
            //a[data-link="This selector needs to be dynamic"]
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rayon Dabre's answer, I've made some corrections:

- Added data-link attributes to the drop down options of the 1st drop down
- Added a missing $ in the second click event handler
- Replaced hardcode 'Iligan' in the line below with the value selected in the first drop down

`$(this).parents(".daselect").find('.uu .uu_dp li a[data-link="' + $(this).attr("data-link") + '"]').parent().show();`

Code here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".uu .uu_dp a").click(function(e){
                $(this).parents(".uu").find(".unregistered_user").text("User: " + $(this).text());
                $(this).parents(".uu").find(".unregistered_user").attr("data-link", $(this).attr("data-link"));
                bbr = $(this).parents(".uc_header").next().find(".uu_cp_form fieldset");
                $(this).parents(".daselect").next().find("form").slideDown();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            //u branch on user management
            $(".ub .ub_dp a").click(function(e){
                $(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").text("Branch: " + $(this).text());
                $(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").attr("data-link", $(this).attr("data-link"));
                //$(this).attr("data-link") will return undefined as clicked element does not have "data-link" attribute
                $(this).parents(".daselect").find(".uu .uu_dp li").hide();
                $(this).parents(".daselect").find('.uu .uu_dp li a[data-link="' + $(this).attr("data-link") + '"]').parent().show();
                //a[data-link="This selector needs to be dynamic"]
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="extend clear daselect">
<div class="btn-group ub align_left margin_right5px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default u_branch" data-toggle="dropdown">Select branch</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>

    <ul class="ub_dp dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp" data-link="Iligan">Iligan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp" data-link="Corporate">Corporate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-identity="cp" data-link="Initao">Initao</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group uu align_left">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default unregistered_user" data-toggle="dropdown">Select User</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>

  <ul class="uu_dp dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="height: 300px;">
    <li><a href="#" data-id="1" data-link="Iligan">User 1 of Iligan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="2" data-link="Iligan">User 2 of Iligan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="3" data-link="Iligan">User 3 of Iligan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="4" data-link="Corporate">User 1 of Corporate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="5" data-link="Corporate">User 2 of Corporate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="6" data-link="Initao">User 1 of Initao</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would say you can improve your code further by saving some jQuery selectors like in the code below, where you have the same selector being constructed twice. You could save it into a temporary variable or chaining all calls (see [jQuery Chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp))

```
$(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").text("Branch: " + $(this).text());
$(this).parents(".ub").find(".u_branch").attr("data-link", $(this).attr("data-link"));
```